# Automatically add routing.xml when bundle is enabled

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to automatically include the routing file of **TotoBundle** when it's enabled in the **AppKernel**:

```
public function registerBundles()
{
   ...
   $bundles[] = new \My\TotoBundle\MyTotoBundle();
   ...
}
```

without having to declare it manually

*app/config/config.yml*

```
toto:
    resource: "@MyTotoBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: I don't understand the context very well, you could define "when it's enabled" ?

Comment: I mean when I enable it in the AppKernel
```public function registerBundles()
    {
...
$bundles[] = new \My\TotoBundle\MyTotoBundle();
...
}```

Answer (score -2):

You can use DependencyInjection in your bundle.
For example :

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\ExampleBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

class NamespaceExampleExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\XMLFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.xml');
        $loader->load('routing.xml');
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried this but it throw an exception :
```InvalidArgumentException in YamlFileLoader.php line 399:
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "myweb_totoroute" (in /var/www/myweb/src/TotoBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/routing.yml). Looked for namespace "myweb_totoroute", found none```

Comment: @Charly If you want to load yml file you should use YamlFileLoader instead of XMLFileLoader as it is in my code snippet.

Comment: @Grzegot Yes but in my case I'm using **Loader\YamlFileLoader** and my file is **routing.yml** and is well formatted.